# Replace many code lines in PHP between tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

I have gotten a page php with this line:

`$url = file_get_contents('http://web.com/rss.php');`

Now I want replace this:

`<link>http://web.com/download/45212/lorem-ipsum</link>
 <link>http://web.com/download/34210/dolor-sit</link>
 <link>http://web.com/download/78954/consectetur-adipiscing</link>
 <link>http://web.com/download/77741/laboris-nisi</link>`...

With this:

`<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/45212</link>
 <link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/34210</link>
 <link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/78954</link>
 <link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/77741</link>`...

I have replaced a part with `str_replace` but I don't know to replace the other part.

This is what i have done for the moment:

```
$url = str_replace('<link>http://web.com/download/','<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/', $url);
```

Comment: so what result do yo uget when you run that str_replace?

Comment: I need numbers.`<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/</link>
 <link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/</link>
 <link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/</link>
 <link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/</link>`...

Comment: looks like it would be working then.

Comment: or are you wanting it to strip off the info after the "/45212" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all with a single line of regex :)

**Regex**

The below regex will detect your middle numbered section....

```
<link>http:\/\/web\.com\/download\/(.*?)\/.*?<\/link>
```

**PHP**

To use this inside PHP you could use this line of code

```
$url = preg_replace("/<link>http:\/\/web\.com\/download\/(.*?)\/.*?<\/link>/m", "<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/$1</link>", $url);
```

This should do exactly what you need!

**Explanation**

The way it works is `preg_replace` looks for `<link>http://web.com/download/` at the start and `/{something}</link>` at the end. It captures the middle area into `$1`

So when we run `preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject)` we tell PHP to just find that middle part (the numbers in your URLS) and embed them into `"<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/$1</link>"`.

I tested it and it seems to be working :)

**Edit: I would propose this answer as best for you as it does everything with a single line, and does not require any `str_replace`. My answer also will function even if the middle section is alphanumeric, and not only if it is numeric.**

Comment: nice one, but the @justarustyspoon solution still better as it catches only the required information from links. Think if the url return different links to be replaced.

Comment: I am aware of that but I was presuming the intent was to switch one set domain for another, so doing a blanket replace may be over-scope as it prevents question asker from doing different matches for different domains later.

Answer (score 2):

All you want to do is:

1. extract the relevant data e.g. the five digit number
2. put the extracted part into a new context

```
    $input = 'http://web.com/download/45212/lorem-ipsum';

    echo preg_replace('/.*\/(\d+).*/', 'http://otherweb.com/get-d/$1', $input);
```

To extract the relevant part, you can use `(\d+)` which means: find one or more digits, the parentheses make this a matching group, so you can access this value via `$1`.

To match and replace the whole line, you have to augment the pattern with `.*` (which means, find any number of any character) before and after the `(\d+)` part.

With this set up, the whole string matches, so the whole string will be replaced.

Comment: good solution, but just like other answer, if the number of digits goes far from 5 or less than 5, it will not catch correctly

Comment: your regex should be ´/.*\/(\d+).*/´ then it will catch any number of digits

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a simple regex to clean up the last part.

Here's how I did it:

```
$messed_up = '
<link>http://web.com/download/45212/lorem-ipsum</link>
<link>http://web.com/download/34210/dolor-sit</link>
<link>http://web.com/download/78954/consectetur-adipiscing</link>
<link>http://web.com/download/77741/laboris-nisi</link>';

// Firstly we can clean up the first part (like you did) with str_replace
$clean = str_replace('web.com/download/','otherweb.com/get-d/', $messed_up);

// After that we'll use preg_replace to get rid of the last part
$clean = preg_replace("/(.+\/\d+)\/.*(<.*)/", "$1$2", $clean);

printf($clean);
/* Returns:
<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/4521</link>
<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/3421</link>
<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/7895</link>
<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/7774</link>
*/
```

I made this quickly so there might be some room for improvement but it definitely works.

You can check out the code in practice [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d68e36e506e5f01d160c4b5f326d44913c881ef).

> If you're interested in learning PHP RegEx [This](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) is a great place to practice.

Comment: your solution is quite good, but if the new url that he wants to replace by contains a number it will broke.

Comment: You're right I've wrote this with only the example in mind. I've updated the answer so it's more flexible now

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the initial part of link with a `token`, and then preg_replace the end of your string searching for the first `/` and replacing with the `</link>`. And so you replace your token with the initial part you desire.

```
$url = str_replace('<link>http://web.com/download/','init', $url);
$url = preg_replace("/\/.+/", "</link>", $url);
$url = str_replace('init', '<link>http://otherweb.com/get-d/', $url);
```